# ZIMPL: 2D variable declaration not recognized in constraint

Tags: linear-programming, scip

I'm having a real challenge declaring a 2D variable in Zimpl. (Parameters seem to work fine.)

The following is my MWE:

```
set I := {1 to 10};
set J := {1 to 5};

param A[I*J] := read InputFile as "n+";
var x[I] binary;
var s[J] binary; # this works but doesn't do what I need
var s2[I*J] binary; # this does what I need but doesn't work

minimize sum<i,j> in I*J with A[i,j] < 5: (s2[i,j] - x[i]) * A[i,j];

# this constraint compiles
subto constraint1:
   forall <j> in J do sum <i> in I with A[i,j] < 5: x[i] <= 1 + s[j];

# this constraint does not compile
subto constraint2:
   forall <j> in J do sum <i> in I with A[i,j] < 5: x[i] <= 1 + s2[i,j];
```

When try to create my lp file, I get

```
Error 133: Unknown symbol "i"
```

Does anyone have any insights into how I can get the second constraint to work? As far as I can tell this is identical to the implementation of the capacitated facility problem (Section 6.3) in the Zimpl user's manual.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the sum over i on the left-hand side of the constraint, but then reference i on the right-hand side as well. Which value of i do you expect there?

What would work is

```
forall <j> in J do sum <i> in I with A[i,j] < 5: (x[i] - s2[i,j]) <= 1;
```

but I am not sure this is what you want to achieve.

Adding Leon's comment to make a more complete answer:

> To add to what Gerald wrote, in ZIMPL sums always only consider the next variable, so you have to put parenthesis to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Gerald wrote, in ZIMPL sums always only consider the next variable, so you have to put parenthesis to make it work.

Comment: Thanks Leon, I added your comment to Gerald's answer as it provided a key piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

at minimize there is the name missing.
It should be minimize obj: sum ...